# Create test Facebook page

Tags: account, facebook-test-users, facebook-graph-api-v2.4

I follow this instruction to create a test Facebook page:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-pages/

But by 3. step (post /user_id/accounts to create the test page) I got following error:

{
"error": {
"message": "Unsupported post request. Object with ID 'xxxxx' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api%22),
"type": "GraphMethodException",
"code": 100,
"error_subcode": 33,
"fbtrace_id": "ARSn-O9fymI7GjnBlXJpi9T
"
}
}

according to the 2. step, I have added pages_manage_metadata and pages_read_engagement access right to the test user. What is still missing here ? can you help ? thanks.

Comment: I have almost the same problem (trying to request /user_id/?fields...) and only manage_pages permission helps, but it is already deprecated and will be removed in 2022.